# Prove $\int_X |f|^p=p\int^{\infty}_{0} t^{p-1}\mu({x: |f(x)>t}) dt\,$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $X$. Let $1\le p<\infty$. Show that, the function $|f|^p$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$ precisely when the function $$t\mapsto t^{p-1}\mu({x:|f(x)>t})$$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$ with respect to Lebesgue measure. In addition prove that 
>   $$\int_X |f|^p=p\int^{\infty}_{0} t^{p-1}\mu({x: |f(x)>t}) dt\,$$

I solved this problem for the case when space is sigma finite but don't know how to solve for general case.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$ \chi_W (x,t) = \{ (x,t) | 0< t< |f(x)| \}$$

Then

$$\int_X |f|^p d\mu= \int_X \int_{[0,|f(x)| ]} pt^{p-1} dt d\mu $$
$$ = \int_X \int_{\mathbb{R}} pt^{p-1} \chi_W (x,t) dt d\mu $$
  $$ =\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_X
   pt^{p-1} \chi_W (x,t) d\mu  dt $$ $$ =
   p\int_{[0,\infty]} t^{p-1} \mu (  \{ x| |f(x)| > t \} ) dt $$

Comment: How can I prove the above if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @adenamsn I think the formula is specific to the Lebesgue measure, which is $\sigma$-finite.