# Hardy-Littlewood strong type estimate, final equation of proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am reading [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy–Littlewood_maximal_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function) proof of strong type estimate and I understand everything but this last equation:

$$2Cp \int_0^\infty \int_{\lvert f \rvert >\frac{1}{2}}t^{p-2} \lvert f \rvert dxdt=C_p \lVert f \rVert_p^p$$ where $C_p$ depends only on $p$ and $d$ where $f$ domain is $R^d$

How can I see it? I think it has to have something in common with the Cavalieri principle : $$\int_{R^d}\lvert f \rvert ^p dx=p\int_0^\infty t^{p-1}m(f>t)dt$$

where $m$ is $d$ dimensional Lebesgue measure, but I can't derive this particular equation.

Comment: I think layer cake representation would be of some help... $f(x)=\int_0^{\infty} \chi_{\{|f|>t \} }dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to extend my comment to an answer. I will call this integral as $I$. Use Fubini's or Tonelli's Theorem to interchange the integrals, we get

$$I=2C_p\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|\int_0^{\infty}t^{p-2}\chi_{ \{|f|>\frac{t}{2}\} }dtdx.$$

Now put  $t^{p-1}=2^{p-1}u$

$=>(p-1)t^{p-2}dt=2^{p-1}du$. We get

$$I=\frac{2^pC_p}{p-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|dx\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{ \{|f|^{p-1}>u \} }du.$$

Use Layer cake representation of a function i.e.,

$$|f(x)|=\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{ \{|f|>t \} }dt.$$

We have,

$$I=\frac{2^pC_p}{p-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|^pdx.$$

Answer (score 1):

Substituting this into our integral gives:

$$
\|Mf\|_p^p \leq p \int_0^\infty t^{p-1} \left( \frac{2(5^d)}{t} \int_{|f| > \frac{t}{2}} |f|\, dx \right) dt.
$$

This simplifies to:

$$
= 2(5^d)p \int_0^\infty \int_{|f| > \frac{t}{2}} t^{p-2} |f|\, dx\, dt.
$$

$$
= 2(5^d)p \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \chi_{\{x:|f(x)| > \frac{t}{2}\}}(x) t^{p-2} |f|\, dx\, dt.
$$

Now, we change the order of integration again (applying Tonelli's theorem):

$$= 2(5^d)p\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  \int_0^\infty  \chi_{\{x:|f(x)| > \frac{t}{2}\}}(x) t^{p-2} |f| \, dt dx.
$$

Observe that $$\chi_{\{x:|f(x)| > \frac{t}{2}\}}(x) = \chi_{\{t:|f(x)| > \frac{t}{2}\}}(t)$$

then,

$$= 2(5^d)p\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  \int_0^\infty  \chi_{\{t:|f(x)| > \frac{t}{2}\}}(t) t^{p-2} |f| \, dt \, dx.
$$

$$
= 2(5^d)p \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left( \int_0^{2|f(x)|} t^{p-2}\, dt \right) |f(x)|\, dx.
$$

The inner integral evaluates to:

$$
\int_0^{2|f(x)|} t^{p-2}\, dt = \frac{1}{p-1} (2|f(x)|)^{p-1}.
$$

Thus, our expression becomes:

$$
= \frac{2 (5^d)p}{p-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)| (2|f(x)|)^{p-1}\, dx.
$$

Simplifying:

$$
= \frac{2^{p}(5^d)p}{p-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)|^p\, dx.
$$

Recognizing the right-hand side as $ \|f\|_p^p $, we get:

$$
\|Mf\|_p^p \le \frac{2^{p} (5^d) p}{p-1} \|f\|_p^p.
$$

Finally, defining $ C_p = \frac{2^{p}(5^d)p}{p-1} $, we obtain the desired inequality:

$$
\|Mf\|_p \le (C_p)^{1/p} \|f\|_p.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The  maximal inequality
$$
\lambda(\{M\,f>t\})\leq\frac{3^d}{t}\|f\|_1
$$
for all $f\in L_1$ plays a role here, as well as the fact that
$\|Mf\|_\infty\leq\|f\|_\infty$ for all $f\in L_\infty$. This last inequality is easily established by noticing that
$$\frac{1}{|B(x;r)|}\int_{B(x;r)}|f(x)|\,dx\leq\|f\|_\infty$$
for all $r>0$.

For $f\in L_p$,  $1<p<\infty$, one can use the trick of splitting $f=g+h$ where $g\in L_1$ and $h\in L_\infty$ and use the $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ results along with applications of [Fubini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1229803/121671) (Cavalieri's principle if you will). This technique is common in getting string bounds in maximal inequalities. One may introduce some additional parameters to find *optimal* bounds. Here is the general idea at work (from Rudin, W., Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition, McGrawHill, 1986, pp. 173-174):

If $1<p<\infty$, then for $0<c<1$ and $t>0$,  let
\begin{align}
g_t= f\mathbb{1}_{\{f>ct\}},\qquad h_t=f\mathbb{1}_{\{f\leq ct\}}.
\end{align}
Clearly $h_t\in L_\infty$ and,
from  Chebyshev's and Hölder's inequalities, we also have  that $g_t\in
L_1$. Hence,
$M\,f\leq M\, g_t + M\, h_t\leq M\, g_t + ct$,
and so,  $\{M\,f>t\}\subset\{M\,g_t>(1-c)t\}$.  By
Hardy--Littlewood's inequality
\begin{align}
\lambda(\{M\,f>t\})\leq \lambda(\{M\,g_t>(1-c)t\})\leq
\frac{3^d}{t(1-c)}\|g_t\|_1=
\frac{3^d}{t(1-c)}\int_{\{f>ct\}} f(x)\,dx
\end{align}
An application of Fubini's theorem shows
\begin{align*}
\|M\,f\|^p_p &= p\int^\infty_0t^{p-1}\lambda(Mf>t)\,dt\\
&\leq \tfrac{3^dp}{1-c} \int^\infty_0 t^{p-2}\int_{\{f>
  ct\}}f(x)\,dx\,dt\\
&=\tfrac{3^dp}{1-c}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)\int^{f/c}_0t^{p-2}\,dt\,dx
=
\tfrac{3^dp c^{1-p}}{(p-1)(1-c)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f^p(x)\,dx
\end{align*}

One can minimize the bound $\tfrac{3^dp c^{1-p}}{(p-1)(1-c)}$, as a function of $c$ to get an *optimal* bound $C_p=(3^dpp'e)^{1/p}$, where $\frac1p+\frac{1}{p'}=1$.